# Why does my cat hate raw fish?

Tags: cats, diet

My cat is used to eating dry cat food available at market.

I thought that my cat would appreciate a new taste. I know the poor quality of canned fish, so I went to local fish market and bought a fish (Rohu) that was still alive.

I cut it into small pieces and placed it in her bowl, however she won't even come near it. When I got her to have a lick of it, she got very angry with me.

I am wondering why she doesn't like it? As wild cats typically like fresh raw fish.

Comment: What sort of fish, size andHow did you present this fish to the cat? Forcing a cat to lick something is not a good idea.

Comment: It is Rohu fish, cut into very small pieces and put on cat bowel

Comment: try sneaking in tiny bits with the dry food or even better canned food you know your cat likes. It may just take some getting used to

Comment: It may be a problem of texture not taste -- a cat who has only ever eaten dry food will have problems recognising anything else as edible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dry food is coated in [animal digest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_digest) to make it taste better to cats. I've been told it's like the flavoring dust on potato chips.

A cat who has only ever eaten food coated with animal digest often won't be interested in food without this coating. If you want to encourage your cat to eat raw fish, you can buy animal digest to sprinkle on top. The most readily available source of animal digest in the US is [Purina's Fortiflora](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001650OE0). I'm not sure how to find it elsewhere (sorry!).

Also note that [some people find animal digest to be a questionable additive](https://truthaboutpetfood.com/popular-vet-recommended-supplement-contains-questionable-ingredient/).

> The legal definition of Animal Digest does not require the ingredient to be sourced from a slaughtered animal. Without this requirement in the legal definition of the pet food/treat/supplement ingredient, Animal Digest can be sourced from animals that have died in the field or a euthanized animal.